# How to Inherit a method with different generic return types

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to inherit a method that returns a Generic BindingList of type ServerType.  For example, let's say I have the following:

```
public interface IServer 
{

    string IpAddress { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string HostName { get; set; }
    string OsVersion { get; set; }

}

public class BaseServer : IServer
{
    private string _IpAddress;
    private string _Name;
    private string _HostName;
    private string _OsVersion;

    public string IpAddress
    {
        get { return _IpAddress; }
        set { _IpAddress = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public string HostName
    {
        get { return _HostName; }
        set { _HostName = value; }
    }

    public string OsVersion
    {
        get { return _OsVersion; }
        set { _OsVersion = value; }
    }
}

public class ServerTypeA : BaseServer { }
public class ServerTypeB : BaseServer { }
public class ServerTypeC : BaseServer { }

public class ServerTypeList : List<ServerTypeA>
{ 

    public BindingList<ServerTypeA> ToBindingList()
    {
        BindingList<ServerTypeA> myBindingList = new BindingList<ServerTypeA>();

        foreach (ServerTypeA item in this.ToList<ServerTypeA>())
        {
            _bl.Add(item);
        }

        return _bl;

    }   
}
```

Is there any way I can do the "ToBindingList" method without having to repeat it in each derived server class and have it use the correct generic type.

Comment: ToBindingList method is just converting a List<T> to a BindingList<T>. You may write a simple extension method for List<T> to do that. It has nothing to do with Server class or anything else in your code.

Comment: It does not look like your implementation would need to repeat `ToBindingList()` implementation. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have other deived classes that I need a BindingList. Different Repository types. so I need to be able to do something like BindingList<RepositoryType> ToBindingList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a base list for all your collections:

```
public class MyListBase<T> : List<T>
    where T: Server
{ 
    public BindingList<T> ToBindingList()
    {
        BindingList<T> myBindingList = new BindingList<T>();
        foreach (T item in this.ToList<T>())
            myBindingList.Add(item);
        return myBindingList;
    }   
}
```

Then use this one to inherit from:

```
public class Repositories : MyListBase<Repository>
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  I made a slight modification to the foreach loop though and replaced the "Repository" datatype you had with a "T".

Answer (score 2):

First offf don´t derive from `List<T>`. Instead *use* it ([favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).

Then make your `Repositories`-class generic:

```
public class Repository : Server
{ 

}

public class Repositories<T> where T: Server
{ 

    private List<T> theList = new List<T>();

    public Repositories<T>(List<T> theList) this.theList = theList; }

    public BindingList<T> ToBindingList()
    {
        BindingList<T> myBindingList = new BindingList<T>();

        foreach (Titem in this.theList)
        {
            _bl.Add(item);
        }

        return _bl;

    }   
}
```

Now you can have `Repositories`-instances of arbitrary classes deriving from `Server`.